# Passing a url to an endpoint as a prop to fetch from in a component in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a chart component I want to reuse with different data.
Inside it I have a fetch function and a prop like so:

```
export let endpoint;
function getData(endpoint) 
{
    return fetch(endpoint)
        .then((d) => d.json());
}
```

Later I use it this way:

```
$: data = getData(endpoint);
```

I pass the prop in the main page via:

```
<SingleBarChart endpoint={endpoint}/>
```

The error is:
throw new TypeError('Failed to parse URL from ' + input, { cause: err })
^

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from undefined
    at new Request (D:\app\frontend\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\request.js:77:15)
    at Agent.fetch (D:\app\frontend\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:116:21)
    ... 4 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at eval (/src/routes/+page.svelte:35:93)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1772:22)
    at Object.default (/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:66:129)
    at eval (/src/routes/+layout.svelte:16:32) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
      at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:563:9)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:643:5)
      at new Request (D:\app\frontend\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\request.js:75:21)
      at Agent.fetch (D:\app\frontend\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:116:21)
      at fetch (D:\app\frontend\node_modules\undici\index.js:95:22)
   

   at getData (/src/lib/components/singleBarChart.svelte:13:9)
      at eval (/src/lib/components/singleBarChart.svelte:47:9)
      at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1772:22)
      at eval (/src/routes/+page.svelte:35:93) {
    input: 'undefined',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
  }
}
```

But, inside single barchart if I change

```
function getData() 
    {
        return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/md_events_team/shot").then((d) => d.json());
    }
```

It works completely well.

I do not understand why, is it that `$: getData(endpoint)` here calls when endpoint is undefined?
It seems like that could be it, because if I give it a dummy URL it works and I can overwrite it too.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will call whenever `endpoint` changes, including the very first time. So if initially endpoint is *undefined* it will try to call the function with `endpoint`.  You can simply check the value before executing the function:

```js
$: endpoint && (data = getData(endpoint));
```